# Lyapunov point or asymptotically stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

is the origin a Lyapunov point or asymptotically stable of the system

\begin{gather*}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x_1}=x_{2}\\
\dot{x_2}=-x_{1}^{n}
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
$n\in \mathbb{N}$?

I don´t see this, anybody can help me with this? or give me a hint? 
thanks

Comment: If I understand, this is a system? So $\dot{x_1} = x_2$ is the first line?

Comment: Did you mean $x_1$ on the first line?

Comment: yes, \dot{x}_1=x_2

Comment: Perhaps you can fix it?

Comment: I meant the question!

Comment: what do you mean with fix it??

Comment: I have fixed the question.

Comment: ok, sorry, i think you was talking about a hint o something to solve ir

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer, it is customary to accept the answer.

Comment: tanks a lot copper.hat!

Answer (score 1):

For odd $n$, the system is stable in the sense of Lyapunov but not asymptotically stable.

Take $V(x) = \frac{1}{n+1} x_1^{n+1} + \frac{1}{2}x_2^2$, and suppose $t \mapsto x(t)$ is a solution. Letting $\phi(t) = V(x(t))$, we see that $\dot{\phi}(t) = 0$, and so $V$ is constant on a trajectory.

For even $n$, the system is not stable in the sense of Lyapunov at the origin.

Note that $\dot{x}_2 \le 0$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $x_0 = (0, -\epsilon)^T$. Then $x_2(t) \le -\epsilon$ for all $t \ge 0$, and since $\dot{x}_1(t) = x_2(t) \le -\epsilon$, we have $x_1(t) \le - \epsilon t$ for all $t \ge 0$. Hence $\|x(t)\| \to \infty$.